# Cumulative sum of pixel values intercepted above a given rasters

Tags: raster, r

I have 41 density calculated rasters, which raster represents a layer of a las file. I need to calculate the cumulative sum of LiDAR points intercepted above a given layer.

density_rasters a vector that includes a 45 raster layer as list. I was suggested to use Reduce function, but it creates RasterLayer with NA values. How can solve it? This is a part of for loop. If it is not clear, I can share all loops.

```
pcs=Reduce("+",density_rasters[(i+1):length(density_rasters)])
```

Comment: Replace the `NAs` by 0 in the rasters ?

Comment: but there is no NA value in the raster normally. The raster is derived using the code you suggested in this link so there is no NA value.  <https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/388138/computing-the-density-for-each-layer-with-lidr/388157?noredirect=1#comment635696_388157>

Comment: There are plenty of `NAs`. `grid_density()` is based on `grid_metrics()` which return `NA` in absence of data. In the case of  `grid_density()` it would have been advised to replace the `NA` by 0 but this is not what is done so you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that thanks! but should I apply replacing `NAs` to 0 while calculating density rasters `grid_density()` ?? I also mean in density rasters there are no `NA` values. When I apply this `Reduce()` function it gives the raster values`NA`... @JRR

Comment: Can't help more without a reproducible example. My capacity to guess the problem out of nothing is limited sorry.

Comment: @JRR - you are right, there are plenty of NA values in rasters. But if I replace them with 0, it will underestimate the cumulative sum. So I will try to find a new method to apply this.

Comment: 0 is a neutral element in a sum